# How to change the image of a particular div on click of that div whose data coming from loop in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have some ul li list whose data is coming from loop.My requirement is once I click to any particular li ,image of that li should be changed to second image(dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff) like active.Again even if I refresh the page that change should be there. Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmcye7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### home.component.html

```html
    <div>
    <ul>
    <li style="border:1px solid;width:25%;margin-bottom:1%;cursor:pointer;padding:4px;" *ngFor="let items of statusdata"  (click)="getData(items)"><span>{{items.id}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{items.name}}</span>
    <span><img [hidden]="nonactive" style="width:20px;height:20px;float:right" src ="/assets/1.png">
    <img [hidden]="active" style="width:20px;height:20px;float:right" src ="/assets/2.png">
    </span>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    declare var $: any;
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      getIt:any;
  statusdata: any;
  getOption:any;
  myData:any;
  myDataGet:any;
  active:boolean = true;
  nonactive:boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {   
      this.statusdata = [{ id: 1,name: 'Angular 2'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Angular 4'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Angular 5'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Angular 6'},
    { id: 5, name: 'Angular 7'}
  ];
console.log(this.getOption);
this.myDataGet = localStorage.getItem('dataSource');
      if(this.myDataGet == 'true' ){
         this.nonactive = true;
         this.active = false;
      }
      else{
          this.nonactive = false;
         this.active = true;
      }   
  }
  getData(items){
      this.myData = items.active;
      localStorage.setItem('dataSource', this.myData);
      this.myDataGet = localStorage.getItem('dataSource');
     /* if(this.myDataGet == 'true' ){
         this.nonactive = true;
         this.active = false;
      }
      else{
          this.nonactive = false;
         this.active = true;
      }*/
  } 


    }
```

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz to replicate the issue? Since we can't see the images and can't really tell whether all are changing on the click event.

Comment: ++ You will need to change the *active* property on each object of the array `statusdata`

Comment: Please find the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmcye7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html , You can check the demo into browser to check locastorage

Comment: Does [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxr3xy) solve the problem? I didn't fully understand the local storage problem (Maybe this solution can get you headed in the right direction?)

Comment: No, Actually my requirement is once I click to any particular li ,image of that li should be changed to second image(https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff) like active.Again even if  I refresh the page that change should be there.I removed the active property from json,because active property should add automatically into json for which we click and should store in localstorage

Answer (score 0):

When you request the data check against storage for the key.

See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cazlo3?file=src/app/app.component.html

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of statusdata" (click)="toggleActive(item, !item.active)">
  <span>{{item.id}}</span>
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <span>
    <img *ngIf="!item?.active || item?.active === false" src ="https://dummyimage.com/qvga" />
    <img *ngIf="item?.active === true" src ="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
  </span>
</li>
```

Component TS

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.statusdata = [
      { id: 1, name: "Angular 2" },
      { id: 2, name: "Angular 4" }
    ];

    this.statusdata.forEach(item => {
      this.getCacheItemStatus(item);
    });
  }
```

```js
  getCacheItemStatus(item) {
    const cachedItem = localStorage.getItem(`item:${item.id}`);
    if (cachedItem) {
      const parse = JSON.parse(cachedItem); // Parse cached version
      item.active = parse.active; // If the cached storage item is active
    }
  }
```

When you toggle the item's status active, cache it.

```js
  toggleActive(item, activeStatus = false) {
    item.active = activeStatus;
    localStorage.setItem(`item:${item.id}`, JSON.stringify(item));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,here Every thing is fine but once we click any li,except that li others will be disable,again if I click on same li which is active that image should not be toggle